# show side menu after login screen

Tags: ios, swift, side-menu

i am creating an ios app but issue is that i don't know that how to add sidemenu after login successfully without login screen i implemented and work successfully but how to use after login screen i am not able to understand because this is my first app that i am creating let me show my code for sidemenu

I am using KYDrawerController For sidemenu

In App Delegate i am done like this

```
var drawer = KYDrawerController.init(drawerDirection: .left, drawerWidth: 260)

let storyBoard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)

        let mainVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Screen2")
        let menuVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Drawer")

        self.drawer.mainViewController = mainVC
        self.drawer.drawerViewController = menuVC

        self.window?.rootViewController = self.drawer
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

and in ViewController On Button Action i am using that from appdelegate like this

```
let appDel = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        appDel.drawer.setDrawerState(.opened, animated: true)
```

Now please tell me how to use after login button tapped and login successful

here i am directly set mainVC but while login i can not set that because i awant to show sidemenu after login

i hope you understand my issue please help mo how to do this

for reference i am done using this example

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Fo491yt4P0

Comment: yes i am implemented

Comment: https://github.com/AkashPatel09/Drawer-Demo

Answer (score 0):

```
func setUpHomeVC() {
    var vc: UIViewController?
    let storyBoard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
    if let user = AppHelper.getCurrentUser() { // if user is login in

        //this is slider menu VC
        let drawerViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Drawer")

        //this is homeVC
        let mainViewController   = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Screen2")
        let drawerController     = KYDrawerController(drawerDirection: .left, drawerWidth: 0.8 * (UIScreen.main.bounds.width))
        let navController = UINavigationController(
            rootViewController: mainViewController)
        navController.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        drawerController.mainViewController = navController
        drawerController.drawerViewController = drawerViewController
        self.window?.rootViewController = drawerController
    }else{
        vc = SignUpVC() // this is user login VC
        let mainVcIntial = UINavigationController(rootViewController:  vc!)
        mainVcIntial.isNavigationBarHidden = true
        self.window?.rootViewController = mainVcIntial
    }
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    self.window?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    setUpHomeVC()
    return true
}
```

hope this will help you.

Comment: what is AppHelper?

Comment: You have to check condition there userIsLogin

Comment: yeah i know we need to check the login condition but you need to tell the OP that what is AppHelper and what is inside it. If he just use your code he will get an error because in his code there is no any AppHelper file or class

Comment: just remove that AppHelper. getCurrentUser() and add userlogin check like if userIsLogin {